# How to get the project name during aws code build?

Tags: python, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

We have our code in a repository named `test` and we have `buildspec.yaml` and `test_engine` folder where the source code is. In buildspec.yaml, I used a python script at post_build to upload artifacts to a s3 bucket `devTest` and folder name inside the s3 bucket as project name (which is `test` in our case). I tried to get the project name using **CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR** in python code as below.

```
CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR = os.environ.get('CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR')
PROJECT_NAME = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR))
```

But **CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR** contains some thing like `/codebuild/output/src888291342/src`. So we are getting **PROJECT_NAME** as `src`. Can some one please let me know if there any way to get the project name.